# Updating points in a mysql database using android studio and php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I currently have a working login/register system. I tried to make it to when a user logs in and clicks a button there username is taken to a Points.php file. Then the php will take the username and add +5 points to that specific users points column. If you help, know that it is very much appreciated, thanks!
This is what I'm currently trying to use:

activity_user_area.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvWelcomeMsg"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:editable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWelcomeMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Earn Points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvWelcomeMsg"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvWelcomeMsg"
        android:id="@+id/bEarn"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

UserAreaActivity.java:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");

        final Button bEarn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEarn);

        TextView tvWelcomeMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomeMsg);
        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);

        // Display user details
        String message = "Welcome, " + username + "!";
        tvWelcomeMsg.setText(message);
        etUsername.setText(username);

        bEarn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = etUsername.toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserAreaActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Points Added")
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserAreaActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Points Not Added")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                EarnRequest earnRequest = new EarnRequest(username, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(UserAreaActivity.this);
                queue.add(earnRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EarnRequest.java:

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class EarnRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String EARN_REQUEST_URL = "https://mysite567356ht7ieyjr6u7je.000webhostapp.com/Points.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public EarnRequest(String username, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, EARN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Points.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id177667_root", "***", "id177667_loginb");
$username = $_POST["username"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET points = points + 5 WHERE username_column =".$username);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Should be `.. WHERE username_column=?` in your prepare-statement (a placeholder `?` instead of `$username`). And you're not doing any error-handlings, you're just assuming that everything is going fine.

Comment: So, your saying my php should look like this?                                       <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id177667_root", "***", "id177667_loginb");
$username = $_POST["username"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET points = points + 5 WHERE username_column" = ?);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
?>

Comment: `mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET points=points+5 WHERE username_column=?");` like this, look at the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First in your php file fetch the points using

```
Select points from user where username_column =$username
```

and then use the update query statement

```
$result=$result + 5;

 UPDATE user SET points = $result WHERE username_column =$username
```